# Trouble with If Statements to fully loop and not fully loop

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

What I am trying to do is if pcount is = 0

```
<cfif (isDefined("session.checkout.quantity.pcount")) eq 0>
```

then loop this but skip the last loop

```
    <cfif BAdd NEQ session.checkout.quantity.bcount>
         <cfinclude template="../../../ddl/bandor.cfm">
```

and if pcount is not equal to 0
(zero is the number 0 in a drop down menu not just blank)

```
<cfif (isDefined("session.checkout.quantity.pcount")) neq 0>
```

then loop this everytime

```
<cfinclude template="../../../ddl/bandor.cfm">
```

This is the full code if anyone can please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<cfif (isDefined("session.checkout.quantity.pcount")) eq 0>
  <cfif BAdd NEQ session.checkout.quantity.bcount>
    <cfinclude template="../../../ddl/bandor.cfm">
  </cfif>
</cfif>
<cfif (isDefined("session.checkout.quantity.pcount")) neq 0>
  <cfinclude template="../../../ddl/bandor.cfm">
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<cfif structKeyExists(session.checkout.quantity, "pcount") AND session.checkout.quantity.pcount eq 0>
  <cfif BAdd NEQ session.checkout.quantity.bcount>
    <cfinclude template="../../../ddl/bandor.cfm">
  </cfif>
<cfelse>
  <cfinclude template="../../../ddl/bandor.cfm">
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a formatted comment to help you understand what went wrong with your code.  This,

```
<cfif (isDefined("session.checkout.quantity.pcount")) eq 0>
```

does not check the value of pcount.  It actually means,

```
if variable session.checkout.quantity.pcount does not exist
```

That's because function isDefined returns a boolean, true or false.  However, the way ColdFusion works, the number 0, as well as the strings, "false", "no", and "0" are interpeted as false.